# MTLTextureDescriptor conundrum

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal

I trying to convert the "Metal By Example" App -TextRendering- for IOS to OSX.  Unfortunately, Xcode tells me that  the MTLTextureDescriptor's storageMode needs to be set to MTLStorageModePrivate and when I do: replaceRegion:mipmapLevel:withBytes:bytesPerRow: throws "failed assertion `CPU access for textures with MTLResourceStorageModePrivate storage mode is disallowed."

```
MTLTextureDescriptor *textureDesc = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:AAPLDepthPixelFormat
            width:MBEFontAtlasSize
            height:MBEFontAtlasSize
            mipmapped:NO];
            
        textureDesc.storageMode = MTLStorageModePrivate;
        textureDesc.usage = MTLTextureUsageRenderTarget | MTLTextureUsageShaderRead | MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite;
        textureDesc.usage = MTLTextureUsageShaderRead;//MTLTextureUsageRenderTarget;
    
        MTLRegion region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, MBEFontAtlasSize, MBEFontAtlasSize);
        _fontTexture = [_device newTextureWithDescriptor:textureDesc];
        [_fontTexture setLabel:@"Font Atlas"];
        [_fontTexture replaceRegion:region mipmapLevel:0 withBytes:_fontAtlas.textureData.bytes bytesPerRow:MBEFontAtlasSize];
```

Any help would be tremendously appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

On macOS, you actually have to explicitly synchronize resources between CPU/RAM and GPU (because the Mac might have a dedicated GPU with its own memory, in contrast to the shared memory model on iOS).

For that, you need to set the storage mode to `managed` and use a `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` to copy memory between the devices (see the [documentation of `managed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlstoragemode/managed)).

Comment: Damn!  I was hoping for a quick fix...  :)   But anyway, Thank you !